# Themed styled components combine props and theme

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components, emotion

Just for curiosity, I am using styled-components in my React application and in there I use the suggested theme to have all colors and sizes everywhere available.

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
export const TestComponent = styled.div`
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.white};
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.white};
    border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.white};
    display: ${({ check }) => check ? 'block' : 'none'};
`;
```

So I am using the theme from the `ThemeProvider` and also an additional check of the outside component.

My question is now, why can I not use it like this:

```
export const TestComponent = styled.div`${({ theme, check }) => (css`
    color: ${theme.white};
    background-color: ${theme.white};
    border: 1px solid ${theme.white};
    display: ${check ? 'block' : 'none'};
`)`;
```

Wouldn't it be more convenient and easier to use ? And if so, why aren't they not suggesting it like this? I am just afraid that it hast some huge disadvantage, which I cannot see right now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's anything wrong with either approach. I've used what you're doing in your first example a lot in a large React app, and had no issue (yet).

That being said, your second example is perfectly valid. You don't even need the `css` helper:

```
const Test = styled.div`
  ${({ theme }) => `color: ${theme.white};`}
`;
```

In general, I use the `css` helper to create abstracted/sharable css chunks:

```
const fontSize = css`
  font-size: ${({ small, large, theme }) => {
    if (small) return `${theme.small}rem`;
    if (large) return `${theme.large}rem`;
    return `${theme.normal}rem`;
  }};
`;


const Test = styled.div`
  ${({ theme }) => `color: ${theme.white};`}
  ${fontSize}
`;
```

And then:

```
<Test small>Hello World</Test>
```

Comment: The `css` helper was more a helper for my IDE to recognize that these are styles and not just a string. But thanks! I will try it out and hope for no issues !